# java - javafx.event.EventHandler is an interface, and JAXB cannot handle an interface

Tags: javafx, jaxb

I have several classes. 
Some of them

Class Game

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "game")
public class Game {
private int scores = 0;
private Field field;

...

 @XmlElement
public int getScores() {
    return scores;
}

public void setScores(int scores) {
    this.scores = scores;
}

@XmlElement
public Field getField() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(Field field) {
    this.field = field;
}


@XmlElement(name="NewShape")
public ArrayList<Shapes> getNewShapes() {
    return newShapes;
}

public void setNewShapes(ArrayList<Shapes> newShapes) {
    this.newShapes = newShapes;
}
...
```

Class Shapes

```
@XmlSeeAlso({RectangleVertic.class, RectangleHoriz.class, Square.class, Angle.class})
public abstract class Shapes {
    private double widthOfSquare, widthBetweenSquares, totalWidth, totalHeight;
    private int countOfSquaresInWidth, countOfSquaresInHeight;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles= new ArrayList();
    private Group group;

public Shapes(){

}

public Shapes(double widthOfSquare, double widthBetweenSquares){
    this.widthOfSquare=widthOfSquare;
    this.widthBetweenSquares=widthBetweenSquares;
}


@XmlElement(type = Group.class)
public Group getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(Group group){
    this.group=group;
}

@XmlTransient
public double getWidthBetweenSquares() {
    return widthBetweenSquares;
}

@XmlTransient
public int getCountOfSquaresInWidth() {
    return countOfSquaresInWidth;
}

@XmlTransient
public int getCountOfSquaresInHeight() {
    return countOfSquaresInHeight;
}

@XmlTransient
public ArrayList<Rectangle> getRectangles() {
    return rectangles;
}

public void setRectangles(ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles) {
    this.rectangles = rectangles;
}

@XmlTransient
public double getTotalWidth() {
    return totalWidth;
}

@XmlTransient
public double getTotalHeight() {
    return totalHeight;
}

@XmlTransient
public double getWidthOfSquare() {
    return widthOfSquare;
}

...

public abstract boolean putRectOnField(int startI, int startJ, ArrayList<Object[]> horizLinesOfSquare, ArrayList<Object[]> verticLinesOfSquare);
public abstract boolean checkPutRectOnField(int startI, int startJ, ArrayList<Object[]> horizLinesOfSquare, ArrayList<Object[]> verticLinesOfSquare);

public abstract int countOfShape();
```

}

Class for marshalling

```
public class JaxbParser implements Parser {
@Override
public Object getObject(File file, Class c) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    return object;
}

@Override
public void saveObject(File file, Object o) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(o.getClass());
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(o,file);
}
```

}

When I try to marshal I get the following error:

> javafx.event.EventDispatcher is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at javafx.event.EventDispatcher
>           at public final javafx.event.EventDispatcher javafx.scene.Node.getEventDispatcher()
>           at javafx.scene.Node
>           at javafx.scene.shape.Shape
>           at javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle
>           at private java.util.ArrayList graphic.Shapes.rectangles
>           at graphic.Shapes
>           at private java.util.ArrayList game.Game.newShapes
>           at game.Game
>
> javafx.scene.input.InputMethodRequests is an interface, and JAXB can't
>   handle interfaces.    this problem is related to the following location:
>         at javafx.scene.input.InputMethodRequests       at public final
>   javafx.scene.input.InputMethodRequests
>   javafx.scene.Node.getInputMethodRequests()        at javafx.scene.Node        at
>   javafx.scene.shape.Shape      at javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle         at
>   private java.util.ArrayList graphic.Shapes.rectangles         at
>   graphic.Shapes        at private java.util.ArrayList game.Game.newShapes
>         at game.Game
>
> javafx.event.EventHandler is an interface, and JAXB can't handle
>   interfaces.   this problem is related to the following location:      at
>   javafx.event.EventHandler         at public final javafx.event.EventHandler 
>   javafx.scene.Node.getOnContextMenuRequested()         at javafx.scene.Node
>         at javafx.scene.shape.Shape         at javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle         at
>   private java.util.ArrayList graphic.Shapes.rectangles         at
>   graphic.Shapes        at private java.util.ArrayList game.Game.newShapes
>         at game.Game

If remove an element Group group from the class Shapes for marshalling, there is no error. 
What am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Group class must be the javafx.scene.Group class.

Source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html

As you can see on the oracle documentation, this class inherit a certain numbers of properties from its superclasses, some of which use interfaces. And JAXB does not manage interfaces.

Unfortunately, i do not see any solution to your problem if you wish to store to XML the full Group Object.

However, if you wish to marshall only some properties (that you need to recreate your Group object), you can use an adapter to save only that.

Source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html

If you opt for the adapter solution and need help, please tell me.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would have long tried to understand why this happens, if not for you.